# VBA to change shape color based on cell value input

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data in column B which is dynamic ( cities can be in any order) , what I am looking is for a VBA code to fill color in the rectangle shape ( I have renamed rectangle shapes to corresponding city names). based on the color of corresponding city.
This is sample list, and actual data can be long, Hence was looking for an automated script to do this task.[image]

Comment: What did you try by your own? What "automated script" should mean?

Comment: Thanks. I am doing this manually by looking at the color and filling the color of rectangle. Conditional formatting is not working on shape. hence was looking is someone can help with a code to perform this task.

Comment: You did not exactly answer my second question... Should I understand that you need an event, to automatically trigger the color change and automatically color the corresponding shape as the new cell interior color? Or to ave a `Sub` which you will run and all the shapes color to be updated according to their correspondent cell value? Will all the necessary cells be in B:B column?

Comment: apologies. I need to have Sub to run to color shapes based on corresponding city, yes , city names will be there in B:B , but order can be changed, A-Z or Z-A

Comment: I would say create your shapes with VBA, naming them, say, Mumbai_1, Mumbai_2, ...,  etc. or according to the cell they will sit on. If you include the cell in the name, then you can also click on any shape to actually select the associated cell or do something else. Coloring is as easy as `Sheet("name_here").Shapes.Range(shp.Name).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Sheet("name_here").Cells("address_here").Interior.Color` where `shp` would be shape object as you create the shape. Mind you shapes have more attributes you can set (tint and shade, brightness, transparency, etc.). Just some ideas here.

Comment: Please, try the code I posted. It is able to trigger the cell color change. It is not a standard event, it is created using a class...

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next approach. It will use a class, able to trigger the interior color change:

1. Insert a class module, name it "clsCelColorCh", copy and place the next code:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents cmBar As Office.CommandBars
Private cellsCountOK As Boolean, arrCurColor(), arrPrevColor(), sCellAddrss() As String
Private sVisbRngAddr As String, i As Long, objSh As Worksheet, cel As Range, rngBB As Range

Public Sub ToSheet(sh As Worksheet)
    Set objSh = sh
End Sub

Public Sub StartWatching()
    Set cmBar = Application.CommandBars
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    cellsCountOK = False
End Sub

Private Sub cmBar_OnUpdate()
    If Not ActiveSheet Is objSh Then Exit Sub
    Set rngBB = Intersect(ActiveWindow.VisibleRange, objSh.Range("B:B"))
    If rngBB Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If sVisbRngAddr <> rngBB.Address And sVisbRngAddr <> "" Then
        Erase sCellAddrss: Erase arrCurColor: Erase arrPrevColor
        sVisbRngAddr = "": cellsCountOK = False        
    End If
    i = -1
    On Error Resume Next
        For Each cel In rngBB.cells
            ReDim Preserve sCellAddrss(i + 1)
            ReDim Preserve arrCurColor(i + 1)
            sCellAddrss(i + 1) = cel.Address
            arrCurColor(i + 1) = cel.Interior.Color
            If arrPrevColor(i + 1) <> arrCurColor(i + 1) Then
                If cellsCountOK = True Then 'call the pseudo event Sub
                    CallByName objSh, "Cell_ColorChange", VbMethod, cel
                        arrPrevColor(i + 1) = arrCurColor(i + 1)
                End If
            End If
                i = i + 1
            If i + 1 >= rngBB.cells.count Then
                cellsCountOK = True
                ReDim Preserve arrPrevColor(UBound(arrCurColor))
                arrPrevColor = arrCurColor
            End If
            arrPrevColor(i + 1) = arrCurColor(i + 1)
        Next
    On Error GoTo 0
        sVisbRngAddr = rngBB.Address
End Sub
```

2. Copy the next code in the sheet to monitor color changes code module (right click on the sheet name and choose `View Code`):

```
Option Explicit

Private ColorChEventMonitor As clsCelColorCh

Public Sub Cell_ColorChange(Target As Range)
     Dim sh As Shape
     On Error Resume Next
       Set sh = Me.Shapes(Target.Value)
     On Error GoTo 0
     If Not sh Is Nothing Then
        sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Target.Interior.Color
     Else
        MsgBox "No shape named as """ & Target.Value & """ in this sheet..."
     End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    StartEventWatching
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    StopEventWatching
End Sub

Private Sub StartEventWatching()
    Set ColorChEventMonitor = New clsCelColorCh
    ColorChEventMonitor.ToSheet Me
    ColorChEventMonitor.StartWatching
End Sub

Private Sub StopEventWatching()
    Set ColorChEventMonitor = Nothing
End Sub
```

3. Deactivate the sheet in discussion (go on a different sheet) and go back. I this way, the sheet `Activate` event starts the color change monitoring.

It does it for color changes in column "B:B".

In order to see it working, of course, there must be so many shapes as records in column "B:B", **named exactly like the cells value**. Anyhow, if a cell value does not match any shape, no error will be raised, a message mentioning that a correspondent shape does not exist will appear.

The pseudo event is triggered when you select another cell. Sometimes, it is triggered only by simple changing the color, but not always...

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @Jogi Singh Didn't you find some time to test the above solution? If tested, didn't it solve your problem?